# Playing spherical videos using YouTube Android API

Tags: android, youtube-api

Is it possible to play spherical youtube [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdZ02-Qenso) using [YouTube Android API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)?

When I tried it just renders spherical video on flat surface like normal video.

Comment: YouTube Android API documentation says nothing about it. Same library seems not updated for a long time. I searched for other alternative libraries but with no succes.

Comment: If the support for it doesn't currently exist, you could try filing a feature request for it on the [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list).